# How to set a column always visible and with a fixed width

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```kotlin
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentSize
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.core.net.toUri
import com.coder.portfolio.R

@Composable
fun LearningsItem(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    serialNumber: Int,
    title: String,
    content: String,
    source: Uri,
) =
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .width(20.dp)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter),
                    text = "$serialNumber"
                )
            }
        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp)
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter),
                        text = title
                    )
                }
            }
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter),
                        text = content
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .width(20.dp)
                .size(20.dp)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.chevron_right_svgrepo_com),
                    contentDescription = ""
                )
            }
        }
    }

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewLearningItem() = LearningsItem(
    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White),
    serialNumber = 10,
    content = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. " +
            "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, " +
            "when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen " +
            "book.",
    title = "Lorem Ipsum",
    source = "https:www.foo.com/xyz".toUri()
)
```

The current implementation will show only the first two columns when the content of the second column larger than the space left on the screen. It makes the third column disappear.

How can I set the third column always visible with a fixed width?

If my current approach is not possible to achieve the desired result with columns, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add weight to the column in the middle:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
    .wrapContentSize()
    .weight(1f)
)
```

[image: Result]